# Getting access violation exception only in x86 release executable using c++/winrt and xaml controls in UWP application

Tags: uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am getting an access violation exception in my c++/winrt UWP application only when running in x86 release mode. x86 debug, x64 release both work with no exceptions being raised. Happens when working with the XAML UI controls (such as MapControl, TextBlock) simply when setting a value or even just instantiation of the object. It happens mid-execution after being called thousands of times previously without issue.

I've tried isolating the problem by reducing the number of worker threads and processing being done in parallel to the main UI thread. In the case of the exception when using the MapControl, it happens inside a CanvasControl Draw callback function, in particular when setting the Geopoint object to be passed onto TrySetViewAsync. It happens after thousands of successful calls to the Draw function.

```cpp
struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
{
    MainPage();

    //GeoLocation
    MapControl m_MapObj;
    Geolocator m_GeoLocObj;
    BasicGeoposition m_currLoc;
    Geopoint m_currPnt;

    void Surface_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl const& sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs const& args);
}


IAsyncAction MainPage::Map_Loaded(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args)
{
        m_MapObj = sender.as<MapControl>();

        auto access = co_await m_GeoLocObj.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (access == GeolocationAccessStatus::Allowed)
        {
            m_GeoLocObj = Geolocator();
            auto geoPos = co_await m_GeoLocObj.GetGeopositionAsync();
            m_currLoc.Latitude = geoPos.Coordinate().Point().Position().Latitude;
            m_currLoc.Longitude = geoPos.Coordinate().Point().Position().Longitude;
        }

        m_MapObj.CenterPoint(float3(m_MapObj.ActualWidth() / 2.0, m_MapObj.ActualHeight() / 2.0, 1.0f));
}



void MainPage::Surface_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl const& sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs const& args)
{
GPSData gpsData = m_DetObjsDB.GetGPSData();


m_currLoc.Latitude = gpsData.latitude;
m_currLoc.Longitude = gpsData.longitude;
m_currLoc.Altitude = 0;

try{
    m_currPnt = m_currLoc;
    m_MapObj.TrySetViewAsync(m_currPnt, 20.0, gpsData.numericalHeading, 0.0);
}
catch (hresult_error const& e){
    printf("%ls\n", e.message().c_str());
}

}
```

The access violation exception gets thrown on the line m_currPnt = m_currLoc. If I try to pass m_currLoc to TrySetViewAsync it then occurs on the function call to TrySetViewAsync. I've tried using local class instantiations such as Geopoint geoPoint(m_currLoc) and that throws an exception as well. I am using the x64 release version as a workaround but need to resolve the case for the x86 release version as well. Any ideas? Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: We cannot see the full picture here. It is unclear, what type `m_currPnt` or `m_currLoc` are, for example. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Understood, only problem is that the full picture is pretty big - I'll provide the declarations of the variables hopefully that will help clarify.

Comment: There's at least one bug in the code you posted: You cannot safely pass arguments to asynchronous function by const ref. You'll need to pass them by value (`IAsyncAction MainPage::Map_Loaded(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs args)`). This ensures, that they live for the duration of the asynchronous call. I don't know if that is what's causing your bug, but it's something you need to fix anyway.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I fixed it and I have good news and bad news. Good news: Doesn't crash anymore; Bad news: It doesn't crash even with the reference passing bug in the code... It left as mysteriously as it came which means I'm sure it will be back. I rearranged some of my libraries which may have affected the manifestation of the bug. I'll try to reproduce it... In the meanwhile, thanks for the help IInspectable!

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not yet, I am having trouble reproducing the access violation. I will update once I make progress.

Comment: OK,please share result once finished it.